# Use something other than H2 for local Build and Unit Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have inherited a Spring Boot app that spins up and runs an H2 in-memory database when I Build or run Unit Tests locally.

I want to address a "real" database instead. I don't know how to configure this or if it's even possible to somehow override whatever is happening.

I suspect it comes from a Spring profile, but I'm not sure.

Here is what I do have in the application.yaml file. To my mind this implies a "default" profile (which is not mentioned anywhere in the yaml file) that Spring uses to fire up the H2 database, but I could be wrong.

```yaml
# list of things that the local profile does that default doesn't:
# uses mysql instead of h2
# logs all queries
# emails erdteam
spring:
  config.activate.on-profile: local
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database?useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&useCursorFetch=true&profileSQL=true
    username: root
    password: root
  jpa.show-sql: true
```

Answer (score 0):

About `default`:
Default profile used by Spring profile is the `default`. All the beans with no profile annotation are specified belongs to the default profile.

About your current `.yml` config, is declared that if `config.activate.on-profile:` equals with `local` you will have another database instead `H2`, for more details check this one resource [spring.config.activate.on-profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-M4/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.properties-and-configuration.change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment).

In your case to change the profile try to replace:

```
    spring:
      config.activate.on-profile: local
```

To:

```
    spring:
      profiles:
        active: local
```

And check if, the `default` profile was changed to `local` and of course if database also was change to another one instead `H2`

Also i recommend you to have a look at [configuration.set-active-spring-profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-M4/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.properties-and-configuration.set-active-spring-profiles)

Let me know if it helped you.